# Euclidean AdS space in Poincaré coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, topology, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I have read [anti-de Sitter (AdS) space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space) and its Euclidean version both in [Global and Poincaré coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#A_simple_definition_for_anti-de_Sitter_space_and_its_properties). For Lorentzian case it is clear how one Poincaré patch cover only one half of the whole AdS space. But when we give an Euclidean rotation, it is said that the resulting space is same both in Poincaré and global coordinates. I mean, the same space is obtained when I give an Euclidean rotation in $\tau$ coordinate of global coordinate system and $t$ coordinate of Poincaré coordinate system.

Please help me how to show this. I am reading [Aharony et al *Large $N$ Field Theories, String Theory and Gravity*](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111) ([pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9905111.pdf)). The statement is made in this paper after Equation (2.29) (on page 45).